# find the distance between _ and _

Tags: linear-algebra

find the distance between:

$(x-1)/3 = (y-2)/(-2) = (z-2) = t$

and

$x/2 = (y-1)/2 = z+1 = t$

I can't really understand this question because the only example i saw in this entire chapter that came close to this was where i find the distance between a point and a plane by setting two variables to $0$ in one equation and plugging that point into the other but this is just bizarrely different.. how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: First, do you understand what are given objects, distance between which you want to compute? And do you know why is the algorithm you used to compute distance between a point and a plane correct?

Comment: all i know is that this is what was written down on my take home assignment. it seems different than everything I tried to study in my book, the algorithm between point and plane was the closest thing i could think of, its probably not the right one.

Comment: I expected answer like “the two objects are lines in 3-dimensional space”. So your problem is to find the distance between two affine subspaces of Eucleidean space. You should first learn some general theory which yields the algorithms for special cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the question is 'What is the distance between two skew lines given in 3D?` we need to find minimum distance between points $T$ and $S$, one of which belongs to one line and the other to the other line. There are two approaches: we can either parametrize the $T$ position with some $t$ parameter and $S$ position with $s$ parameter, then express their distance as a function of $t$ and $s$:
$$d(T,S) = \|T(t)-S(s)\|$$
(assuming here $T$ and $S$ are interpreted as vectors $S=[x_S, y_S, z_S], T=[x_T, y_T, z_T]$) and minimize it...

or we can simplify the solution to some vector calculations.

Let's assume we have a point $T_0$ which belongs to the first line and the line's direction vector $T_v$, so that $T$ can be expressed as $$T(t)=T_0 + t\cdot T_v,$$ similary for the other line a point $S_0$ and vector $S_v$ give $$S(s)=S_0 + s\cdot S_v.$$ Now let's define the normalized cross-product $N$ of the two direction vectors: $$D = T_v\times S_v,$$ $$N = \frac D{|D|}.$$
Now, the equation $N\cdot X=0$ defines a plane $\pi$ through $(0,0,0)$ parallel to the two lines; for any real $d$ equation $N\cdot X=d$ defines a plane parallel to $\pi$, $|d|$ apart in one direction or the other (depending on the $d$ sign).

So expression $N\cdot X$ defines a distance of the point $X$ from the plane $\pi$, with sign indicating the direction with respect to $N$ vector. Consequently $N\cdot T(t) = N\cdot T_0 = \textrm{const.}$ is a distance of the first line from the $\pi$ plane, $N\cdot S_0$ is a distance of the other line from $\pi$ and finally $$N\cdot(T_0-S_0)$$ is a distance between the two lines.
This is, because the two skew lines, when projected orthogonally on $\pi$ plane give two crossing lines, so there exists a line perpendicular to $\pi$ which meets both given lines, and that line's segment makes the shortest distance between the two lines.

In the example given

$(x-1)/3 = (y-2)/(-2) = (z-2) = t$

we have

$\begin{align}
x &= 1 + 3t \\
y &= 2 - 2t \\
z &= 2 + t
\end{align}$

so $T_0 = [1,2,2], T_v = [3,-2,1]$
and

$x/2 = (y-1)/2 = z+1 = s$

that's

$\begin{align}
x &= 0 + 2s \\
y &= 1 + 2s \\
z &= -1 + s
\end{align}$

so $S_0 = [0,1,-1], S_v = [2,2,1]$.

Then $$D = [3,-2,1]\times[2,2,1] = [-4,-1,10]$$ $$|D|=\sqrt{16+1+100}=\sqrt{117}$$ $$N=\tfrac 1{\sqrt{117}}[-4,-1,10]$$
and finally the distance sought is
$\begin{align}
dist & = N\cdot(T_0-S_0) \\
 & = \tfrac 1{\sqrt{117}}[-4,-1,10]\cdot\left([1,2,2] - [0,1,-1]\right) \\
 & = \tfrac 1{\sqrt{117}}[-4,-1,10]\cdot[1,1,3] \\
 & = \tfrac 1{\sqrt{117}} \cdot (-4-1+30) \\
 & = \tfrac {25}{\sqrt{117}} \end{align}$

...or something like that. ;)

Comment: woooowwwww thanks!! that was such a well drawn out explanation and now I realize what the 0 subscript is for after being confused about it for a while. So I could summarize this as: the distance is the dot product of (To-So) and N, where N is the unit vector u oppositely directed to v, and where v is the cross product of Tv and Sv. right?

Comment: I appreciate the confirmation that I got the right answer.

Comment: @JL Yes' that's generally right, although you don't need to introduce $u$ vector and distinguish its direction as opposite to $v$ - the direction is quite meaningless, because distance should be taken by abs() function (which I forgot when writing my answer, sorry) and you can always switch the $N$ direction simply by switching the order of cross product terms: $$A\times B=-B\times A.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The formula $$a(x-b) = c(y-d) = e(z-f)$$ describes a line that passes through the point $(b, d, f)$.  The formula
$$a(x-b) = c(y-d) = e(z-f) = t$$
describes a specifc point on that line.  The $x$-coordinate of that point is given by:
$$
a(x-b) = t \iff x = t/a + b
$$
the other coordinates can be found, similarly.

So each of the formulas your teacher provided defines a point.  Find the coordinates of the two points (in terms of t), then find the distance between the two points.

Comment: ...but keep in mind the $t$ variables in both equations are independent, so you better replace one of them with, say, $q$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: No, I disagree.  I think the expected interpretation is that the $t$s in the two formulas are the same. The answer will be the square-root of a quadratic function of $t$.

Comment: The objects are two lines. Each line is given as a set of points, parametrized with variable $t\in \mathbb R$, which makes them numer lines. But the distance between these lines certainly is NOT defined as a distance between points corresponding to the same value of both parameters – with such definition the distance would depend on the positions of zero on each line as well as on scale of each line.

Comment: At this point we are arguing interpretation of what "$=t$" means.  I would say that unless you know the teacher in question or the Geometry book in question, there is no way to be certain which interpretation is correct.  All I can say is that for the Geometry teacher I had and the Geometry book I used, my interpretation would be correct.

Comment: ok so once i got the 2 points i use the formula d(u,v) = ||u-v|| ?

i ended up getting sqrt(17t^2 - 6t + 11). is that what you got?

Comment: i got another problem like this on a quiz in class but the t in the second part was an s, and i tried using the d(u,v) formula but he said that was wrong..

Comment: so he probably didnt know what he was doing when he made em both t and shoulda made the second one s

Comment: It is hard to interpret the intention of the question-asker, but I agree with this answerer:  I think the $t$ in both equations represents the *same* parameter, not independent parameters, and this question does *not* ask for the student to minimize the distance between two skew lines, but rather to find the distance between two *points*, both of whose coordinates are given in terms of a (single) parameter $t$ (and to express that distance in terms of $t$). But the question is ambiguously phrased.

Answer (score 2):

I take the interpretation that we are given two (skew) lines in 3-space, and are asked to find the distance between them. A typical point on the first line has coordinates $(3r+1,2-2r,r+2)$. A typical point on the second line has coordinates $(2s, 2s+1,s-1)$. Minimizing the distance is the same as minimizing the square of the distance, and the square of the distance is $$(3r+1-2s)^2+(1-2r-2s)^2+(r-s+3)^2$$ So now the question is, do you know how to minimize this function of two variables?

Comment: ...no? I'm afraid I don't recall this minimizing terminology

Comment: do you mean reduce it?

Comment: So, I guess you haven't done any multivariable calculus. Never mind, there's another way which I'll post soon.

Comment: no only calculus 2.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, without Calculus (but with the same assumptions and the same notation as my other answer).

One line is $(1,2,2)+(3,-2,1)r$, the other is $(0,1,-1)+(2,2,1)s$. We want to minimize the distance from $P$ to $Q$ over all points $P$ on the first line, $Q$ on the second. For the minimizing points, the line segment joining $P$ and $Q$ will be normal to both lines. So its direction vector will be normal to the direction vectors $(3,-2,1)$ and $(2,2,1)$ of the two lines. So the direction vector will be the cross product of these two vectors, $$(3,-2,1)\times(2,2,1)=(-4,-1,10)$$ So we want a point on the first line, plus a multiple of this vector, to be a point on the second line: we want $$(3r+1,2−2r,r+2)+(-4t,-t,10t)=(2s,2s+1,s−1)$$ Now this is a system of three linear equations in three unknowns, so you solve it; then you plug the values you get for $r$ and $s$ into the distance formula in my other answer, and you get the (square of the) distance between the two lines.

Comment: can you tell me how you got (3,−2,1)r and (2,2,1)s exactly? and how did you get (3r+1,2−2r,r+2)+(−4t,−t,10t)=(2s,2s+1,s−1)?

Comment: Look at the equations for the lines in my other answer; I just rewrote those. And the other equation is exactly what I wrote: point on first line (which is as given in other answer), plus multiple of the $(-1,-1,10)$ vector, equals point on 2nd line (as given in other answer). You tagged the question "linear algebra", so I assume you know how to add vectors, multiply a vector by a scalar, and such.

Comment: I know how to add vectors and multiply them by a scalar, I just didnt see how you got (3,−2,1)r and (2,2,1)s to begin with. and I can see now that those are the multiplied and summed out versions of the vector above. all i can see is that (3,−2,1)r and (2,2,1)s are the denominators in each equation. is there a general formula or step by step process you can give me for solving this equation this way?

Comment: Denominators? I don't see any denominators. Anyway, if you're given two lines, and you want to find the distancce between them by this method, you write each line in the form $u+vt$ for appropriate vectors $u$ and $v$; you take the cross-product of the two $v$-vectors to get a vector $w$; you write $(u_1+v_1t_1)+t_3w=u_2+v_2t_2$, which is three equations in the three unknowns $t_1,t_2,t_3$; solve the system; then the distance is the length of the line segment from $u_1+v_1t_1$ to $u_2+v_2t_2$. Why not make up an example, and try it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a third answer, which doesn't use Calculus or Linear Algebra. We join my first answer at $$(3r+1−2s)^2+(1−2r−2s)^2+(r−s+3)^2$$ which we are supposed to minimize. Multiply this out to get $$9s^2-6rs+14r^2-14s+8r+11$$ (and be sure to check my arithmetic throughout this computation). Do some "completing the square": $$9s^2-6rs+r^2+13r^2-14s+8r+11=(3s-r)^2-(14/3)(3s-r)+13r^2+8r-(14/3)r+11$$ $$=(3s-r)^2-(14/3)(3s-r)+(49/9)+13r^2+(10/3)r+11-(49/9)$$ $$=(3s-r-(7/3))^2+(1/13)(169r^2+(130/3)r+(25/9))+(50/9)-(25/117)$$ $$=(3s-r-(7/3))^2+(1/13)((13r+(5/3))^2)+(625/117)$$ Now it's clear that the minimum value of this last expression is $625/117$, so if I have done my arithmetic correctly (which I do not guarantee) then the answer is the square root of this number, so $25\sqrt{13}/39$.